# Is there some set sentence for 「XXXX年度海外予算会議社長講評」?

Tags: translation, set-phrases

I wonder, if there is some set sentence for the heading 「XXXX年度｛ねんど｝海外｛かいがい｝予算｛よさん｝会議｛かいぎ｝社長｛しゃちょう｝講評｛こうひょう｝」?

I have tried to translate it on my own, but I had difficulties with posing the word "meeting" in the right place:

> President’s comment on the meeting concerning overseas budget in the
>   fiscal year XXXX

Could you please tell me, if my translation sounds natural and if there is some set sentence, could you please teach me it?

Comment: That is only a long noun, not a sentence.

Comment: Yes, in Japanese maybe it is a long noun, but in English it will be a sentence.

Comment: ^ Really? It looks like a noun phrase... "(President's) comment (on the meeting) (concerning overseas budget) (in the fiscal year XXXX)" ← all words/phrases in parentheses are modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your translation is natural.
 This should be interpreted as 
  ((((xxxx年度)海外予算)会議)((社長)(講評)))

Each elements's connectivity is depend on its meaning.

新型重戦車デザインコンペティション総統講評

is

(((((新型)重戦車))(デザインコンペティション))((総統)(講評)))

So English version should be

Führer's comment on new heavy tank design competition

Answer (score 1):

Does President give a「講評」 on the annual overseas budget - Overseas Operation Budget for Fiscal Year of 2017 - at the board meeting?　Maybe. But I’ve seldom heard of the set of word、社長講評 being used on such an important issue.

The issues like an annual budget and business plans of a legit organization are discussed, studied, examined, reviewed to the bone by participating officers or directors and finally approved by the President.

The president’ role there is not to simply make the kind of “講評” given by the judges at a speech contest. It should be something like 社長（の）方針、発言、意見、見解、決定、承認, but unlikely be a “講評,” which sounds like a nonchalant third party’s comment.

In net, your translation is correct. But Japanese text you quoted is unrealistic.